# Output in HTML page a mySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this

> $sql = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN jr_softwarecheck LIKE \'%sony\' AND
>   jr_othersoftware LIKE \'%sony%\' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS totalcount FROM
>   jos_jreviews_content WHERE jr_softwarecheck LIKE \'%sony%\' OR
>   jr_othersoftware LIKE \'%sony%\'";

I want to output results in HTML pages. I run a Joomla based site. 
How can I do that?
Sorry but I'm not so skilled in PHP, I'm learning.

Expected result in HTML page (frontend), example:

SONY Products: 105

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: good god, don't do SQL queries like this!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, use it like this:

```php
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN jr_softwarecheck LIKE \'%sony\' AND jr_othersoftware LIKE \'%sony%\' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS totalcount FROM jos_jreviews_content WHERE jr_softwarecheck LIKE \'%sony%\' OR jr_othersoftware LIKE \'%sony%\'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql); // This will run the query on the connected datababse
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ // Since you are using just a SUM to count results, you don't need to loop
        echo "Sony Products: ".$row['totalcount']; // $row['totalcount'] is the result of the totalcount from your MySQL query put into the $row variable
    }
```

I hope this helps you out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //do something
}
```